# Where to put my packages

Tags: packages, system

I wrote a few packages with various functions. Now I would like to put these packages to a location that I can "Get" them via `<<name` ( I prefer a directory "packages" in my Mathematica system).

I read the article [Where will I put packages](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25990/where-will-i-put-packages/25996#25996) but this did not work. Can anyone give me a hint where to put the packages  *.wl files) so that I can get them simply via e.g. `<<name` after startup of Mathematica?

Comment: Try placing them here: `FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Applications"}]`. Should work.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin: Thanks! Seems to work. I´ve putted them in the ´$UserBaseDirectory´ ... missed the "Applications".

Comment: related: [75539](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/75539/5478)

Comment: @Kuba: Thank you! Did not find this post during my search.

Comment: @mgamer I've found a better one, if you disagree it is a duplicate, let me know.

Comment: @Kuba: Yes, you´re right ;-)